# Split content of select into different fields

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to send the values that are separated by an pipe to 2 different fields. For some reason it won't work.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function folder(selectVeld)
{
   // Stuur informatie terug
   var id = (selectVeld.options[selectVeld.selectedIndex].value).split('|');
   // Id
   document.getElementsByName('folder_id').value = id[0];
   // Naam
   document.getElementsByName('folder_naam').value = id[1];
}
</script>

<tr>    
    <td><?php echo $lang['folder']; ?>:</td>
    <td><select name="folder" onChange="folder(this)">
    <option value="geen"><?php echo $lang['no_folder']; ?></option>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT id, naam FROM 2_folder ORDER BY naam ASC";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$con);  
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    ?>
        <option <?php if($row['id'].'|'.$row['naam'] == $folder){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $row['id'].'|'.$row['naam']; ?>"><?php echo $row['naam'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?></select>
    </td>
</tr>

    <input type="text" name="folder_id" value="<?php echo $folder_id; ?>" size="5" style="background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" />

    <input type="text" name="folder_naam" value="<?php echo $folder_naam; ?>" size="5" style="background-color: #e7e7e9" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: What is `nr`? Try replacing `nr` with `0`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. [nr] was left there when trying to find an solution. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have avoided this problem by using only the folder_id and find the name with an seperate query after sending the form.

Answer (score 2):

[`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns a `array` of elements, even if there is only a single element with that name.

```
document.getElementsByName('folder_id')[0].value = id[0];
document.getElementsByName('folder_naam')[0].value = id[1];
```

should do the trick. [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sGtcg/1/)

Comment: <pedantic>It returns a `NodeList`, not an actual array.</pedantic>

Comment: No result, even when adding [] or [0] to the form fields. document.getElementById is also not working.

Comment: @muiter What doesn't work? Is the select list empty? Can you please post the generated **HTML** code?

Comment: The select list is working, I can use $folder after sending the form.
The problem is that the values $row['id'].'|'.$row['naam'] are not send to the form fields.